# Return type from WKWebView's evaluateJavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I'm adding a `style` object to the HTML via JavaScript in my custom renderer:

```
string jsScript = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = 'body {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);";

var res = await Control.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(new NSString(jsScript));
```

If I do this I get

> Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type}

The operation is successful, but there is something wrong with the return type. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [WebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(String) Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710788/return-type-from-wkwebviews-evaluatejavascript) seems that require return value, so can you try to change your javascript that can return value?

Comment: But how? I tried to add `return style.innerText;` at the end and get *4: Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "Es ist eine JavaScript-Ausnahme aufgetreten" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SyntaxError: Return statements are only valid inside functions.*

Comment: adding return statement need your script to be a function, usually you can write your function into your webpage's js and call your function from EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(new NSString(jsScript)), here's a sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#invoking-javascript

Comment: I'm changing the CSS afterwards currently (JS is not embedded into website). If I wrap it into a function and call it with `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync()` it get's executed, but at that time it is too late for the CSS to take effect. The correct timing only works if I use `WKUserScript` and there the JS is executed without a problem. Here I don't need to wrap it into a function. The return statement seems not to be needed if you wrap it into a function. To sum it up: Wrapping it into a function doesn't bring the error and solves the problem. For my use case I still use `WKUserScript`.

Comment: You could add an answer if you want. I'll accept it.